# passing a variable from a JSON array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json

I am pulling information from a web page into my app in the form of JSON arrays. The arrays themselves are not static in that some of the items in the arrays will change from time to time. The first array contains various fields but the problem in this case is that it will send a variable which has to be passed to a different function elsewhere in my code to form part of a url. For example, the first array would be something like:

```
{"i_one":"some info","i_two":"some more info","p_id":"3"}]
```

The `p_id` part, i.e.`:3`, needs to be passed into the example url shown below to replace the {ID}.

"http://http://www.somesite.com/json/files/project_%@",p_id

How can I do this when the variable(s) received from the array are only available within the function that the array is parsed in?

Ok so,
First the array is pulled from a url via this:

```
#define getDataURL @"http://www.somesite.com/json/files/jarray.txt"
```

Then the data is retrieved and parsed like this:

```
//Retrieve data
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];  
//Loop through Json Array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{ NSString * bID= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"p_id"];}
```

This seems to work fine to this point.
However, elsewhere in the code in another function, I then try to use p_id and pass it into a url like this:

```
NSString *imageUrl = NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somesite.com/json/files/project_%@ ", [bID];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];}];
```

At this point I get "use of undeclared identifier bID"

Comment: That array is a dictionary.

Comment: "into Xcode"? How so? Is it not your application, rather, that receives the data?

Answer (score 2):

OK, first off. Your array is actually a dictionary.

Using `NSJSONSerialization` will give you an object like...

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"i_one" : @"some info",
    @"i_two" : @"some more info",
    @"p_id" : @"3"
};
```

To put the pid into a string you can use this...

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somesite.com/json/files/project_%@", dictionary[@"p_id"]];
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough. I am parsing the array/dictionary like this: for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    { NSString * bID= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"p_id"];} But if I try to use "p_id" elsewhere I get undeclared identifier. It's due to the variable scope I know but I don't know how to get round that?

Comment: Also,the array is being accessed/imported into the code from the web via: NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil]; I hope that makes a bit more sense now?

Comment: You need to show all your non working code and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Edited the original post

Comment: Ok. So how many instances of a pid do you actually get in that for loop? And which one do you want to use later on in the code? The simplest way would be to create a property for the class and use that to store the pid. But in an array you normally store multiple things which is why I ask.

Comment: p_id is only one part of the retrieved array and is the part used in another function. Other parts of the array are: p_name, p_description, p_thumbnail. So, p_id is used to retrieve a url that relates directly to a particular block of info. In the example I gave p_id is equal to "3" which, when appended to the example url, retrieves information relative to project 3 or info block 3 or whatever you want to call it. As I said originally, the main array(s) are subject to change and therefore the info returned via p_id would change accordingly. This is why p_id is passed to a separate function.

Comment: Can you add the result of `NSLog(jsonArray.description);` to your question please. I really don't think you have an array here at all.